# Simple Open Source Task Manager

Tags: open-source, task, taskmanager

I would like to make a task manager server here in my company. I want it to be very simple just to delegate tasks to others and email them about it.

We alrady use a Project Manager tool. So what I'm seeking for is a very simple tool, with a very simple interface and a single purpose: delagate taks and have everyone involved on them to be updated by email as soon the task is updated.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time later I found this one: [Taskfreak](http://www.taskfreak.com/)